# Связь между сущностями

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Имеются сущности Клиенты и Услуги. 
Клиент может пользоваться несколькими услугами", но "Услуга может предоставляться нескольким клиентам". Получается связь «многие ко многим».
Как ее раздробить на один ко многим?

Comment: А зачем вам "дробить" если не секрет ?

Comment: @Радик Камалов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8):

Добавьте третью сущность Услуги клиента, и свяжите ее с каждой из остальных.

Comment: +1 называется развязочная таблица.

Comment: Да все верно. Единственное, что с точки зрения реального мира это должна быть сущность ОказаниеУслуги(Заказ, Наряд ...) которая отражает собственно сам факт оказания конкретной услуги конкретному клиенту. Ну там ещё дату указать, стоимость и т.п.

Comment: Т.е. это журнал (запись клиентов на услугу) ?

Comment: Смотря что понимать под словом "журнал".
Главное, что эта сущность имеет составной первичный ключ, каждая часть которого есть внешний ключ к связываемой через нее сущности.